# SBT: Custom commands aggregation

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-project

I'm looking for a way to create a custom command in sbt for multi-project structure in a such way:

- This command shouldn't do anything for the root project
- This command should make some action in subprojects
- Executing command for the root project should trigger execution such commands for subproject

I have this in my build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Custom command",
    commands += Command.command("customCommand") { state =>
      state
    }
  )
  .aggregate(a, b)

lazy val a = project
  .settings(
    commands += Command.command("customCommand") { state =>
      println("Hello")
      state
    }
  )

lazy val b = project
  .settings(
    commands += Command.command("customCommand") { state =>
      println("Hey there")
      state
    }
  )
```

Unfortunately, I get nothing in the sbt shell:

```
sbt:Custom command> customCommand
sbt:Custom command>
```

The expected output is:

```
sbt:Custom command> customCommand
Hello
Hey there
sbt:Custom command>
```

The order doesn't matter.

So it looks like my command is executed for the `root` project only. Is there any way to tell sbt to execute `customCommand` for subproject first?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you don't really need a command and can do everything you want with a task. You can define a task key, override it in your subprojects and the aggregating project will do what you expect (aggregate):

```
lazy val customTask = taskKey[Unit]("My custom task")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(a, b)

lazy val a = project
  .settings(
    customTask := { println("Hello") }
  )

lazy val b = project
  .settings(
    customTask := { println("Hey there") }
  )
```

Here's how it works:

```
> a/customTask
Hello
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 5, 2018 9:31:43 PM
> b/customTask
Hey there
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 5, 2018 9:31:47 PM
> customTask
Hey there
Hello
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 5, 2018 9:31:50 PM
```

---

Check sbt documentation on [Commands](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Commands.html), you need it only if you need to manipulate the build state explicitly (which is hard to do carefully), call other existing commands or modify settings (which you normally shouldn't):

> Typically, you would resort to a command when you need to do something that’s **impossible in a regular task**.

If you still need a command, I think you cannot override it in subprojects and aggregate like a task, but you can probably define it once and inside it dispatch on the project it is called from. I really doubt you want it.